# conditional formatting assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, comparison

I am struggling with a simple function in excel. So I've come to the experts.

I am trying to create a sheet to track a lottery pool. Each person will have 7 cells populated from column B to Column H. I will then store the results of each nights winning numbers in another set of columns. I want to then have the 7 picks from each person compare the winning numbers and color in if there's a match.

I tried using conditional format with a couple of different formulas but as soon as 1 of the numbers entered in the winning nights columns all the peoples columns are colored.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it e.g.:

- select all the numbers of the persons
- go to home - conditional formatting - new rule
- select "use a formula to ..."
- Enter formula:
  `=COUNTIF($B$1:$H$1,B3)>0`
- specify your desired format

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU THANK YOU! That was the formula i was attempting but for some reason it was highlighting all of the persons numbers not just the matching ones. I don't remember what I did wrong but this worked perfectly! thanks again.